# Writing non-standard evaluation syntax with use of magrittr reverse pipe

Tags: r, dataframe, magrittr, nse

I'm looking at simple way of simplifying code.

## Example

The `sqrt` function could be easily applied to the subset of columns below.

```
require(magrittr)
mtcars[,-which(colnames(mtcars) %in% 
                 c("mpg", "cyl", "drat", "wt", "carb",
                   "hp", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear"))] %<>%
  sqrt
```

## Problem

I'm interested in applying other transformations to the subset ***without*** the need to type the whole subsetting sequence again.

For instance the code:

```
mtcars[,-which(colnames(mtcars) %in% 
                 c("mpg", "cyl", "drat", "wt", "carb",
                   "hp", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear"))] %<>%
  .data * 1000
```

will return error:

```
Error in function_list[[k]](value) : could not find function ".data"
```

Same with syntax using `.`. My question is: syntax-wise, how can i get the same effect as in the `sqrt` function but applying longer function to the passed subset?

Comment: replace `.data * 1000` by `\`*\`(1000)` ? to call it as a function and not an operator ?

Comment: @Tensibai  It's interest approach, but how can I efficiently pass a number of operations? Multiplication is only an example of potential usage. In practice I would like to a couple of things for this data.

Comment: Write a custom function which return compatible output ? (vector for vector, etc) or just an anonymous function as @Uwe showcased in his/her answer. I vote for the 1, so you can test the function alone too. I.e: `%<>%  { . * 10 - 1000 }` for example

Comment: @Tensibai Thanks very much, I'm using both of your suggestions, I will be happy to accept if you care to write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about?

```
sel_cols <- setdiff(colnames(mtcars), 
                    c("mpg", "cyl", "drat", "wt", "carb",
                      "hp", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear"))
mtcars[, sel_cols] %<>% {sqrt(.) %>% `*`(1000)}
```

Or a `data.table` approach?

```
library(data.table)
sel_cols <- setdiff(colnames(mtcars), 
                    c("mpg", "cyl", "drat", "wt", "carb",
                      "hp", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear"))

dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)
dt[, (sel_cols) := lapply(.SD, sqrt), .SDcols = sel_cols][]
```

and combined with pipe:

```
dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)
dt[, (sel_cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {sqrt(x) %>% `*`(1000)}), .SDcols = sel_cols][]
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I think that first suggestion is quite similar to what Tensiabi proposed in his comment. In terms of the data table approach, it's a very interesting but slightly longish.

Comment: The last [] is unnecessary in the data.table approaches, the orignal dt is updated. Advantage is data.table update in place without copy (on huge datasets it avoid creating a new vector to replace original one). Using lapply is needed in case there's more than 1 column returned, same thing with magrittr btw. cc @konrad

Comment: @Uwe you should prefer `setDT(mtcars)` instead of `as.data.table` as setDT will key the data.table at the same time, allowing cross join, etc.

Comment: @Tensibai I did this purposefully because `setDT(mtcars)` results in an error message `Can not convert 'mtcars' to data.table by reference because binding is locked. It is very likely that 'mtcars' resides within a package (or an environment) that is locked to prevent modifying its variable bindings. Try copying the object to your current environment, ex: var <- copy(var) and then using setDT again.` Instead of `setDT(copy(mtcars))` I used `dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)` to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Konrad Yes, you're right. In a production code the last `[]` would be superfluous. However, I didn't want people who are less experienced in `data.table` to get confused when they run the code snippet and nothing gets printed. So, I used it as a shorthand for `print(dt)`.

Comment: @Uwe the 'back pipe' of magrittr doesn't print either as it modifies the source (just for information)